# how to set up the default view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to setup `calculatorViewController` as default when launching the app but instead of tah i get `creatorViewController` as the main view controller. however when tapped differents segmented and then tap back first tab `calculatorViewController` this is shown normal.
How can i fix it???

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: CustomSegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var CalculatorViewController: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var EvidenceViewController: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var CreatorsViewController: UIView!

@IBAction func customSegmentValueChanged(_ sender: CustomSegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            CalculatorViewController.isHidden = false
            EvidenceViewController.isHidden = true
            CreatorsViewController.isHidden = true
        case 1:
            CalculatorViewController.isHidden = true
            EvidenceViewController.isHidden = false
            CreatorsViewController.isHidden = true
        case 2:
            CalculatorViewController.isHidden = true
            EvidenceViewController.isHidden = true
            CreatorsViewController.isHidden = false
        default:
            CalculatorViewController.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0 in your viewdidload?

Comment: oh, yes I did, but problem is still the same.

Comment: you need to add more information, maybe add a GitHub demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    //if you need to use tag then use this line otherwise skip it.
     segmentController.tag = segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex
    // only segmentController.tag line 
     self.segmentControllAction(segmentController)

    }
```

and your outlet is ok dont change it

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide these two UiView(EvidenceViewController and CreatorsViewController) and show this(CalculatorViewController) in storyboard  as default.

Comment: or try to display in first of the UIView Layer and hide the other UIView